# Simple python: palindrome function (returns true if palindrome, false if not palindrome)

Tags: python, palindrome

Good evening folks,

I'm working on an assignment for a course in Python. Our job is to write a function that returns True if the string it takes is a palindrome, otherwise it returns False. The following code reports False to the console for nonpalindromes, but does not report anything to the console when it is a palindrome. I hypothesize it's getting lost in either the recursive call or the second elif statement, but I really don't know where it's going wrong. Any help greatly appreciated :) Here's the code:

```
def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def first(word):
    return word[0]

def isPalindrome(word):
    if(len(word)<1):                        
        print("You entered a blank word!")
    elif(len(word)==1):  
        return True 
    elif(first(word)==last(word)): 
        if(middle(word)==''):
            return True
        isPalindrome(middle(word))
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What it should take as the input? I assume a list, is that correct?

Comment: Well, as a replacement, there's always the classic `word == reverse(word)`, unless it must be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

There are much easier ways to check for palindrome using Python. That aside, for your current approach you'll need to *return* the output of the recursive call, else your function will *return* `None` in that `elif` branch:

```
return isPalindrome(middle(word))
```

---

You can, for example, simply reverse the string and check if the reversed and original string are equal:

```
word == word[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]
```

`word[::-1]` reverses `word`. This checks whether `word` backwards is the same as `word`.